# Ionic2 LoadingController spinner animation not working

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to show Loading animation using **Ionic2** for long service progress report:

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...',
    spinner: 'ripple' // <<------ Is that correct?
});

this.loading.present();
```

The result is a text box without any spinner.

This is 09/22/2016 Ionic2 using latest beta (11) and I cannot actually find any example like above anywhere. Could this be a future feature documented but not yet implemented?

I am talking about the Ionic2 `LoadingController` documentations [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/2.0.0-beta.10/api/components/loading/Loading/)

Answer (score 2):

Is `ripple` a custom spinner? Otherwise, you can check the *by default* available spinners [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/spinner/Spinner/):

```
ios 
ios-small   
bubbles 
circles 
crescent    
dots
```

> The spinner name should be passed in the spinner property, and any
>   optional HTML can be passed in the content property. **If you do not
>   pass a value to spinner the loading indicator will use the spinner
>   specified by the mode**. To set the spinner name across the app, set the
>   value of loadingSpinner in your app's config. To hide the spinner, set
>   loadingSpinner: 'hide' in the app's config or pass spinner: 'hide' in
>   the loading options

So another option, would be to just use the specified spynner according to the mode like this:

```
this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content: 'Please wait...'
});

this.loading.present();
```

Comment: I tried other names ("dots" for example), and also: "ripple" is a standard spinner. Checking the LoadingOptions interface, the "spinner" parameter looks legit...

Answer (score 0):

Thing is it might be that the Ionic team just put a way of extending the Loading control using a custom spinner, meaning that you have to put a SVG file name to the property.

It just looks obvious that you can put there one of the built-in spinner names. 
Then again, it is reasonable to keep the app's design straight with the same spinner in all loaders. Guess that could be more bolded in the docs...